# Regex: matching ICU plurals

Tags: javascript, regex, icu

Simple ICU plurals example:

```
I have {count, plural,
  one {apple}
  other {apples}
}
```

I want to extract plural forms (one, other) and appropriate text to them (apple, apples) from this example string.

I reached some result with this Regex:

```
(?<=plural,)(?:.*?)(?:\s*)(.*[^\s])(?:\s*{.*)}
```

but it matches only first plural form:

```
Full match  15-29   `
  one {apple}`
Group 1.    18-21   `one`
```

How to match all forms?

Comment: Are you using ICU regex engine? Could you please add what programming language you are using for this task?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, I using only regex101.com and regular expressions RegExp in JS

Comment: If you want to use it in JS later, please add JS tag.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds in regex.

Comment: @ctwheels, I did not tested it in JS yet, only with regex101

Comment: If you can use a different regex engine (other than JS's engine), you can use `(?:\bplural,|\G(?!\A))\s*(\S+)\s*{([^}]*)}`. Unfortunately, JavaScript's engine doesn't support many tokens and your best bet is likely to use string functions with loops and regex. The only alternative is to create a grouping for each potential line, but this can get stupid fast if you have 2+ possible lines. See `\bplural,\s*(\S+)\s*{([^}]*)}\s*(\S+)\s*{([^}]*)}`

Comment: @ctwheels thank you, it works fine, but unfortunately not in JS

Comment: @AndrewAndrew that's why I said if you can use something other than JS's engine. The JavaScript engine has little support for *special* tokens and only provides basic regex support (for the most part)